# Order by select box

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am running query's on my batsmen table and would like to sort the results A-Z and Z-A as well as High to Low on top score by using a select option box without reloading the page. I am having a problem working out how to get the AJAX js working with the php and select box any ideas on how to do this, i can't find any useful tutorials. I have this code so far:

Controller(PHP):

```
    $batsmenQuery = Batsmen::where('approved', '=', 1);

   switch ($request->SortbyList){
        case 0:
            $batsmenQuery = $batsmenQuery->orderBy('name', 'DESC');
            break;
        case 1:
            $batsmenQuery = $batsmenQuery->orderBy('name', 'ASC');
            break;
        case 2:
            $batsmenQuery = $batsmenQuery->orderBy('hs', 'ASC');
            break;
        case 3:
            $batsmenQuery = $batsmenQuery->orderBy('hs', 'DESC');
            break;
            default:
                $batsmenQuery = $batsmenQuery->orderBy('name', 'DESC');


    }

    $batsmen= $batsmenQuery->paginate(40);
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="sort">
                <select name="SortbyList" id="SortBy">
                    <option value="0">A to Z</option>
                    <option value="1">Z to A</option>
                    <option value="2">Highest Score</option>
                    <option value="3">Lowest Score</option>

                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

javascript:

```
 $('#SortBy').on('change', function(e){

 });
```

Any ideas on how to javascript for this work to switch through statements related on whats been clicked in the select box?

Comment: Ajax requests are relatively costly to make, why would you want to reload the sorted data instead of sorting the already loaded data? You could just update the DOM of you page to reflect the requested sorting.

Comment: I dont want to reload the sorted date i want to sort the loaded data through the select box without reloading the page

Comment: You want to load the data from your server using Ajax. This while you already have the data necessary from the initial page load. It is cheaper on resources to order the already gotten data instead of using an Ajax request to load it.

Comment: no the data is loaded through PHP, the javascript is handling the switch with the select box see above

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking after jquery ajax request, take a look at this example

```
// Have this in your .blade.php file 
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<script> 
  var url_variable = "{{route('your_route_name')}}";
</script>


.
.
.
$('#SortBy').on('change', function(e){
   $.ajax({
       url: url_variable,
       type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'JSON',
       data: {
           _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
           SortbyList : $("#SortbyList").val()
       }
   })
   .success(function (response) {
       console.log(response);
       // Now build the table as you want with javascript and replace it 

   })
   .error(function (xhr, status, response) {
       console.log(xhr.responseText);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how you can do what you want, you have to change some things in this code acord your own methods.

```
 $('#SortBy').on('change', function(e){
     $.ajax({
               url: "new_values.php", // This is the url you make the request
               data: {SortbyList : this.value}, // Here you can send to the server the info you want in this case is only the value for the selected item 
               success: function(result){

                 if(result){
                     $("#SortBy").empty();  //This erase all the preview values 
                     var new_options = ''
                     //This loop create the new values
                     $.each(result, function(k,v){
                          new_options += '<option value="'+ v.value +'">'+  v.name +'</option>'
                     });
                     //Now we have all the values we can put on the select
                     $("#SortBy").append(new_options);
                 }

        });
 });
```

Comment: Doesnt work my friend, seems to try but nothing happens

Comment: How are you doing that ? did you log your result ? are you using Laravel ?

Comment: Could you make a jsfidle https://jsfiddle.net/ using my example to see your code ?

Comment: Just checked the log nothing is happening with that code

Comment: Try to simulate the post using postman, the error could be on the server side